# How to Store multiple Rows from GridView Winform Devexpress to Access Database?

Tags: c#, ms-access, gridview, devexpress

How to Store Multiple rows from GridView to Access Database. I have code to store Single Focused row but i need to Store Multiple Rows ? How to Complete My Task ?

this code I used to store single focused row

```
 OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:/Srihari/Samples.accdb");
            conn.Open();



            string s1 = (string)gridView1.GetFocusedRowCellValue("Item");
            string s2 = (string)gridView1.GetFocusedRowCellValue("Description");
            string s3 = (string)gridView1.GetFocusedRowCellValue("UoM");
            object quant = gridView1.GetFocusedRowCellValue("Quantity");
            object price = gridView1.GetFocusedRowCellValue("Price");
            object taxp = gridView1.GetFocusedRowCellValue("Tax in Percentage");
            object taxa = gridView1.GetFocusedRowCellValue("Tax in Amount");
            object total = gridView1.GetFocusedRowCellValue("Total");


            int a = Convert.ToInt32(quant);
            int b = Convert.ToInt32(price);
            int c = Convert.ToInt32(taxp);
            int d = Convert.ToInt32(taxa);
            int e = Convert.ToInt32(total);


                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("insert into gridview(Item,Description,UoM,Quantity,Price,TaxinPercentage,TaxinAmount,Total) values ('" + s1 + "','" + s2 + "','" + s3 + "', " + a + " ,  " + b + " , " + c + " , " + d + "  , " + e + " )", conn);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Inserted Successful","Information",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                Close();
```

This code work for Single Row but i need to store Multiple Rows, Please Help me.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To obtain all the selected rows, use the [GridView GetSelectedRows](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_GetSelectedRowstopic) method. Go through the documentation to know more about this feature.

Here is the way that that you can follow. You can get the multiple selected rows from the xtragrid as below.

```
int[] selRows = ((GridView)gridControl1.MainView).GetSelectedRows();
DataRowView selRow = (DataRowView)(((GridView)gridControl1.MainView).GetRow(selRows[0]));
txtName.Text = selRow["name"].ToString();
```

Here is an example that let you to do [Multiple selection using checkbox (web style)](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E1271)

References:
[How to select rows via an unbound checkbox column](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/A371)
[How to get multiple selected rows in Grid Control](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q293787)
[Get values from selected rows from XtraGrid with multiple select and grouping?](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q454211)

**Edit: By Comment**

To traverse through gridview rows you have to see below topic, which clear you everything that you need..
[Traversing Rows](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/CustomDocument742)
[Locating Rows](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/CustomDocument1029)

Example code snippet

```
using DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base;

ColumnView View = gridControl1.MainView as ColumnView;
View.BeginUpdate();
try {
   int rowHandle = 0;
   DevExpress.XtraGrid.Columns.GridColumn col = View.Columns["Category"];
   while(true) {
      // locating the next row 
      rowHandle = View.LocateByValue(rowHandle, col, "SPORTS");
      // exiting the loop if no row is found 
      if (rowHandle == DevExpress.XtraGrid.GridControl.InvalidRowHandle)
         break;
      // perform specific operations on the row found here 
      // ... 
      rowHandle++;
   }
} finally { View.EndUpdate(); }
```

Reference:
[Iterating over all rows in the grid (not the data source) and retrieving values only for the visible rows](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q291307)
[Iterate through Grid rows](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q227338)

Comment: Hi Niranjan, Thanks for answering but i need to save all data from GridView to Access Datbase not Selected Rows I need to Store all Rows.